# Unexpected behaviour when plotting 3D scenes with mayavi

Tags: python, mayavi

I want to plot a sphere with latitudes 3D using mayavi. But I don't want the the latitudes in an equidistant angular range, but in an arangement according to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment

This should result in spherical segments which have the same surface area.
So far... Lets consider theta to be the polar angle and phi to be the azimutal angle. Then I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab


## Create a sphere
r = 1.0
pi = np.pi
cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin
arccos=np.arccos
phi, theta = np.mgrid[-0.5*pi:0.5*pi:101j, 0:1*pi:101j]

x = r*sin(phi)*cos(theta)
y = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta)
z = r*cos(phi)

## Basic settings mlab
mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(500, 500))
mlab.clf()

mlab.mesh(x , y , z, color=(0.9,0.,0.), opacity=0.3)

phi1=np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
theta1=arccos(np.linspace(0,1,11))
for i in range(len(theta1)):
    x_pol = np.cos(phi1) * np.cos(theta1[i])
    y_pol = np.sin(phi1) * np.cos(theta1[i])
    z_pol = np.ones_like(phi1) * np.sin(theta1[i])

    mlab.plot3d(x_pol, y_pol, z_pol, color=(0,0,0), opacity=0.2, tube_radius=None)

mlab.show()
```

The result is shown in image0 below.
[image: image0]

As you can see, the arrangement of the segments is not correctly ordered. So I changed the order in theta1:

```
theta1=arccos(np.linspace(1,0,11))
```

The result is shown in image1 below. As you can see, the arrangement of the segments didn't change.

[image: image1]

So, why is that? When I arrange the angular spacing from 0...1 this should come up with a different result then a spacing from 1...0. But actually it doesn't?!?

Has anyone a clue, what I did wrong?

Thanks

[image0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anS8H.png)
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADAj2.png)

Comment: both images are the same (different url, though)

Comment: Correct, that's the problem... image0 is with theta1 ranging from 0 to 1 and image1 is with theta1 ranging from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The ranges have the same values. The segments are the same, but in reversed order.
See the values of `theta`:

```
In [1]: np.flip(np.linspace(0,1,11), 0), np.linspace(1,0,11)
Out[1]: 
(array([ 1. ,  0.9,  0.8,  0.7,  0.6,  0.5,  0.4,  0.3,  0.2,  0.1,  0. ]),
 array([ 1. ,  0.9,  0.8,  0.7,  0.6,  0.5,  0.4,  0.3,  0.2,  0.1,  0. ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I am not sure, whether I got your point. In the first case theta looks like this:

```
In [1]: np.arccos(np.linspace(1,0,11))
Out [1]:
array([0.        , 0.45102681, 0.64350111, 0.79539883, 0.92729522,
    1.04719755, 1.15927948, 1.26610367, 1.36943841, 1.47062891,
    1.57079633])
```

In the second case it looks like:

```
In [1]: np.arccos(np.linspace(0,1,11))
Out [1]:
array([1.57079633, 1.47062891, 1.36943841, 1.26610367, 1.15927948,
    1.04719755, 0.92729522, 0.79539883, 0.64350111, 0.45102681,
    0.        ])
```

So to me, it seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

sometimes it takes quite a time for me ^^

I figured out, what I did wrong. I simply changed

```
np.arccos(np.linspace(0,1,11))
```

to

```
np.pi/2 - np.arccos(np.linspace(0,1,11))
```

which produces the correct output.

[correct Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkzTJ.png)

Well, sometimes you (I) don't see the forest for the trees... ^^

Greetings...